# Why I am getting "Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: null is not a function" when using Pdfmake with Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, pdfmake

I am using PDFmake to generate pdf files in the Angular application. I am able to generate all the required results using pdfmake library.

But I am getting **'Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: null is not a function'** this error in the console log as shown below.

[image]

```
pdfmake.js:31998 Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: null is not a function
    at __webpack_modules__.9662.module.exports (pdfmake.js:29878:1)
    at new Promise (pdfmake.js:36500:1)
    at ZoneAwarePromise.then (zone.js:1034:1)
    at pdfmake.js:36565:1
    at new Promise (pdfmake.js:36504:1)
    at ZoneAwarePromise.then (pdfmake.js:36564:1)
    at push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/animations.js.AnimationRendererFactory._scheduleCountTask (animations.js:152:1)
    at animations.js:181:1
    at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391:1)
    at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150:1)
module.exports @ pdfmake.js:31998
dispatchEvent @ pdfmake.js:36416
(anonymous) @ pdfmake.js:36429
module.exports @ pdfmake.js:33533
(anonymous) @ pdfmake.js:36426
queue.<computed> @ pdfmake.js:34218
run @ pdfmake.js:34194
listener @ pdfmake.js:34205
```

```
const documentDefinition = {
  content: [
    {
      table: {
        widths: [100, '*', 200, '*'],
        body: [
          ['width=100', 'star-sized', 'width=200', 'star-sized'],
          [
            'fixed-width cells have exactly the specified width',
            { text: 'nothing interesting here', italics: true, color: 'gray' },
            { text: 'nothing interesting here', italics: true, color: 'gray' },
            { text: 'nothing interesting here', italics: true, color: 'gray' },
          ],
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
  pageSize: 'A4',
  pageOrientation: 'landscape',
  pageMargins: [20, 30, 20, 30],
};
pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition).download(`myPDF.pdf`);
```

Comment: seems like your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72473965/why-i-am-getting-unhandled-promise-rejection-typeerror-null-is-not-a-function. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide code snippet of the line causing this error. But I believe that you didn't handle the case where your promise 's `reject()` block you need to provide a `catch` block to handle promise rejection.

Comment: I have added the corresponding code snippet and error.

Comment: @GauravNagpure pretty sure this is not the correct code snippet

Comment: This is the correct snippet, I have rechecked it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error **downgrading** pdfMake from `v0.2.4` to `v0.1.70` for angular `v9.0.5` did the trick for getting rid of the error. Maybe the new version pdfMake isn't compatible with the old angular version.